# Nativescript Angular persistent BottomSheet

Tags: angular, nativescript, bottom-sheet, nativescript-angular

I am using Angular with https://github.com/Akylas/nativescript-material-components , but as I understand this plugin can only build modal bottom-sheet, not a persistent, that I want.

My question is: how can I create persistent bottom-sheet using nativescript angular?

Thank you for replying.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e28CM.png)

Comment: You may use GridLayout / DockLayout for a persistent view at bottom of your page.

Comment: If by persistent you mean a docked layout than you can create this on your own. See how I have achieved this here: https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/apod/apod.component.html#L21-L23  - to see the docked layout in action go to APOD section of this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nativescript.curiosity&hl=en_US

Comment: I want to have something like android material bottom-sheet. If it will be only DockLayout I need to animations for collapsing it

Comment: You may use the Animation APIs to animate layout from bottom. If you still prefer native bottom sheet, you will have to modify the delegates in plugin to prevent dismissal of bottom sheet.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you create the issue in the repo to implement this feature, I adapted the bottom sheet component to work with angular, will find the time to research about this behavior to implement it. :D